# Remove tableview footer line

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, ios8

I set a image background to a tableview like this:

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
UIImageView *tableBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]];
[tableBackgroundView setFrame: self.tableView.frame];
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:tableBackgroundView];
```

If I move the scroll bar down, it always shows a gray line at the end. I tried

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

but its still not working.

[image]

Comment: Did you turn off the separators? Set the separator style to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`.

Comment: @CrimsonChris I updated the question, I tried UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following line in viewDidLoad :

[self.tableView setTableFooterView:[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero]];

This will remove extra separators from tableview

hope it will work...

Comment: that's what I did. you can see my post with the line as well.